# Sage 50 Accounts 2010 wont run on windows 7

Tags: event-log, sage

I have sucessfuly installed Sage 50 Accounts 2010 onto my 32 bit Windows 7 machine, yet whenever i try to run it i encounter -

> Log Name:      Application
>   Source:        Application Error
>   Date:          24/05/2010 17:14:13
>   Event ID:      1000
>   Task Category: (100)
>   Level:         Error
>   Keywords:      Classic
>   User:          N/A
>   Computer:      LukeThomas-PC.domain.co.uk
>   Description:
>   Faulting application name: Sage.SBD.Platform.Installation.SoftwareUpdates.UI.exe,
>   version: 2.0.0.91, time stamp: 0x4a8c22fe
>   Faulting module name: igdumd32.dll, version: 8.15.10.1872, time stamp: 0x4a848a05
>   Exception code: 0xc0000409
>   Fault offset: 0x00012f96
>   Faulting process id: 0x1778
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01cafb5c2493b609
>   Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Sage SBD\Sage.SBD.Platform.Installation.SoftwareUpdates.UI.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\igdumd32.dll
>   Report Id: 63e2246b-674f-11df-96ba-002564c97988
>   Event Xml:
>     
>       
>       1000
>       2
>       100
>       0x80000000000000
>       
>       5062
>       Application
>       LukeThomas-PC.domain.co.uk
>       
>     
>     
>       Sage.SBD.Platform.Installation.SoftwareUpdates.UI.exe
>       2.0.0.91
>       4a8c22fe
>       igdumd32.dll
>       8.15.10.1872
>       4a848a05
>       c0000409
>       00012f96
>       1778
>       01cafb5c2493b609
>       C:\Program Files\Common Files\Sage SBD\Sage.SBD.Platform.Installation.SoftwareUpdates.UI.exe
>       C:\Windows\system32\igdumd32.dll
>       63e2246b-674f-11df-96ba-002564c97988

Any help would be appreciated as i cant find anything about this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

close sage 
go to **C:\Program Data\Sage\SBD Software updates**
 
delete the **softwareupdate.dat** fie and there is another one there too remove that. Then Re-apply all updates.

note, the program data folder is hidden so you will need to go to folder options in control panel and show hidden files and folders to see it